# How to query Jenkins to determine if a still building pipeline job has been aborted

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

Within a Jenkinfile pipeline script, how do you query the running job state to tell if it has been aborted?

Normally a FlowInterruptedException or AbortException (if a script was running) will be raised but these can be caught and ignored.  Also scripts will not exit immediately if it has multiple statements.

I tried looking at 'currentBuild.Result' but it doesn't seem to be set until the build has complete.  Something in 'currentBuild.rawBuild' perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing that would automatically set the build status if the exception has been caught. If you *want* such exceptions to set a build status, but let the script continue, you can write for example

```
try {
    somethingSlow()
} catch (InterruptedException x) {
    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
    echo 'Ignoring abort attempt at this spot'
}
// proceed
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  Unfortunately my catch blocks need to be a bit more complicated as my "somethingSlow" could be a shell script and that raises an AbortException instead of an InterruptedException when the job is terminated.  Assuming the aborted shell script returns the right exit code, I can tell if it was aborted or not but not 100%.

Comment: By the way you could also use: `sh 'some-script; echo $? > result'; def exit = Integer.parseInt(readFile('result').trim()); if (exit != 0) {…}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately writing the exit code to a file is not a good way to detect job termination either. Batch files on windows can sometimes execute a few extra lines after jenkins termination. The 'result' file will almost always be written so you still end up having to figure out if the exit code was for an actual error or for termination.

Comment: Actually that sounded like a bug so I added JENKINS-34489

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a watchdog branch in a parallel step. It uses a global to keep track of the watchdog state which could be dangerous, I don't know if accessing globals in 'parallel' is threadsafe. It even works if 'bat' ignores the termination and doesn't raise an exception at all.

Code:

```
runWithAbortCheck { abortState ->
    // run all tests, print which failed

    node ('windows') {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                bat "ping 127.0.0.1 -n ${10-i}"
            } catch (e) {
                echo "${i} FAIL"
                currentBuild.result = "UNSTABLE"
                // continue with remaining tests
            }
            abortCheck(abortState)  // sometimes bat doesn't even raise an exception! so check here
        }
    }
}


def runWithAbortCheck(closure) {
    def abortState = [complete:false, aborted:false]
    parallel (
        "_watchdog": {
            try {
                waitUntil { abortState.complete || abortState.aborted }
            } catch (e) {
                abortState.aborted = true
                echo "caught: ${e}"
                throw e
            } finally {
                abortState.complete = true
            }
        },

        "work": {
            try {
                closure.call(abortState)
            }
            finally {
                abortState.complete = true
            }
        },

        "failFast": true
    )
}

def _abortCheckInstant(abortState) {
    if (abortState.aborted) {
        echo "Job Aborted Detected"
        throw new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException(Result.ABORTED)
    }
}

def abortCheck(abortState) {
    _abortCheckInstant(abortState)
    sleep time:500, unit:"MILLISECONDS"
    _abortCheckInstant(abortState)
}
```